# Can I simulate an unobserved confounder to test sensitivity?

Tags: regression, causality, confounding, endogeneity

I have a linear regression model Y ~ b0 + b1*X, with X and Y as continously measured variables (say age -> income).

Assume I know from theory that there is an unobservable variable Z that is correlated with both X and Y. Thus, not including Z in the model would bias b1.

I now want to test how strongly Z would have to be correlated with X and Y such that b1 would become insignificant (i.e., p-value > 0.05). Based on theory, I assume that cor(Z,X) = 0.3 and cor(Z,Y) = 0.4.

My approach would by to simulate a variable Z' based on the correlations assumed from the literature, and then estimate Y ~ b0 + b1*X + b2*Z' to see how this changes by estimate of b1.

I am a bit concerned that I am oberlooking something, as there seems to be a lot of literature on this kind of analysis (also called "sensitivity analysis", https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tipr/readme/README.html). However, I only found packages that solve this problem for binary X (e.g., treatment and control group), but my X is continous.

What do you think? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The `obsSens` package for R will do these sensitivity analyses for continuous $x$ values.

I have been meaning to add the simulation option like you suggest to the package, but have not gotten around to it yet.

If you want to simulate data "by hand" with the given correlations, you can follow the general example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930211/generate-uncorrelated-variables-each-well-correlated-with-existing-response-vari/44930649#44930649), Just make your current $x$ and $y$ variables the first 2 in the matrix with a 3rd random variable $z$ as the 3rd column.  Then for the desired correlation matrix, make sure to put in the existing correlation between $x$ and $y$ so that it is properly reproduced).